# Angular Static Resource Help

Tags: javascript, static-resources, angularjs

I have a feeling this is going to be an impossible ask and will probably get closed but I am truly stumped and hopefully just writing it out will help get the wheels turning.

I am trying to work with old angular code that is listed as a static resource. Whenever I try to edit the `ang.app.js` file in the resource, the entire angular app breaks. I know this sounds crazy but it even happens when I just simply put in a `console.log()` and I don't change any of the code. I downloaded the working zip file, unzipped it, edited it, zipped it back up, and uploaded as the new static resource. I even had a co-worker double check that I am uploading the right file with the additional `console.log('test');` to make sure I wasn't just making a stupid mistake.

Does anyone have any guesses as to why any changes to the angular file it breaks? Is there something basic about angular and static resources I am missing? Does anyone have any suggestions on how to start troubleshooting?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cause:**

Vistualforce page was expecting `/js/src/ang.app.‌​js` path while static resource giving the path as `/tcrmCreditContact‌​Tabs/js/src/ang.app.‌​js` after uploading.

**Resolution:**

Zip files available inside tcrmCreditContact‌ folder instead of zipping tcrmCreditContact‌ folder itself.